# Ideal file path line breaking within a cell longtable tabu

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, columns, tabu

I am creating a table which has file name, source and destination file paths, and a short description of each file. The description and flag fields have spaces so the line break can be automatic.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X[1 , l ] |X[1 , l ] | X[1 , l ]| X[.2\linewidth , l ]| X[1 , l ]|}\firsthline\hline
    % -----------------These are headings----------------------------------%
    Filename & Source & Destination & Flag & Functions \\ \hline
    %
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {{\bfseries  Continued from previous page}} \\ \hline
    %
    Filename & Source & Destination & Flag & Functions \\ \hline
    \endhead
    %
    \hline \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %-----------Headings end---------------------------------
    %--------------------------table body starts-------------------
    somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallyreallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & description of the said file \\
    somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallyreallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & description of the said file \\
    somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallyreallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & description of the said file \\
    somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallyreallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & somereallylongpathtoafile & description of the said file \\
    .
    .
    .
    %--------------------------table body ends-------------------
\end{longtabu}
%===============================================================
\end{document}
```

My question is:

What should be the ideal line break for a file path? Should it be at slashes (folders) or should it be within folder names? and how?

Also, in `[a4paper]{article}` class what is the `\linewidth` or `\textwidth` size? That way, I can fix the table column width and let the forced line break to happen.

Below is the output which I get.

[image: A really long table with long file paths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some elements that may help you :

1. I think the best way is to make the hyphenation on the slashes.
2. To view the values of `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` for a precise place in your document, you could use the package `layout` that may help you printing the values inside the output document (view code below).
3. A way to help you making your hyphenations on your table is to use the `url` package (view code below).

Here is the code that prints the values of `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` in the output document at the specified place and that make the hyphenations for you :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
textwidth: \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth}

linewidth: \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\linewidth}

\path{C:/salut/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucouc/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/coucou/}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output :
[image]

**EDIT**

Concerning your example, `somereallylongpathtoafile` will not be treated by the `url` package if it doesn't contain slashes. So you may need some more stuff in this case.

Comment: Lol, thank you. `somereallylongpathtoafile` is really of no use without the slashes. Btw, my Preamble has `hyperref` package too. Won't that conflict with `url`?

Comment: I haven't try it, but according to this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before, I would recommend to load `hyperref` add the end of your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your post. It had me figured that 5 column table in an a4paper was a bad idea. So decided to use a3paper and the `geometry` package to change the page margins. The table now looks good.